# Maximize $\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)$ subject to $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i=C$

Tags: inequality

Suppose that $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in (0,1)$. I was wondering if there is a neat upper bound of $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)$$ subject to $$\prod_{i=1}^n x_i=C.$$

Thank you!

Comment: The case $n=2$ may help you: if $y=C/x$, then $(1-x)(1-C/x)$ is unbounded on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @paf note that the constraint $y\in(0,1)$ implies $x>C$, so we can't send $x$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_i=-\log(x_i)$ and let
$$
  f(a)=\log(1-e^{-a}).
$$
Then
$$
  f'(a)=\frac{e^{-a}}{1-e^{-a}}=\frac1{e^a-1}
$$
is decreasing, so $f$ is strictly concave down. By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),
$$
  \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(a_i)\leq f\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right).
$$
Now $f(a_i)=\log(1-e^{-a_i})=\log(1-x_i)$ and
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^na_i=-\log\left(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\right)=-\log C,
$$
so
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)\leq n\log\left(1-C^{\frac1n}\right).
$$
Exponentiating,
$$
  \prod_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)\leq\left(1-C^{\frac1n}\right)^n
$$
with equality iff all the $x_i$ are equal to $C^{\frac1n}$.